# Is There a Way to Emit All JavaScript Calls Made to Browser from Blazor?

Tags: javascript, .net-core, google-chrome-devtools, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am attempting to track down an integration issue with `IJSRuntime` in Blazor (server-side).  I do have the call I am making, with everything seeming to be configured properly, and no exceptions thrown.  However, I want to see *exactly* what is being invoked in the browser so I can know for sure what is happening and can further copy/paste to the integration partner if needed.

Is there a way to:

1. Have Blazor emit the actual JavaScript being sent to the browser (via logging, etc)?
2. Have Chrome/browser show JavaScript calls being made by Blazor via Developer Tools?

I have spent some time searching this and nothing obvious has presented itself, so wanted to try my luck here to see if someone might assist in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Not without modifying the source. Blazor doesn't send JavaScript to the browser - it sends a request that identifies the correct function to call and passes the parameters to it - so there is no JavaScript code to log. To log that function and its parameters would require a modification to the Blazor source - or you could log from the function you are calling, or use the debugger to capture the information.